# python: elasticsearch-dsl: update body not fully transfered

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch, indexing, updates

'I am accessing elasticsearch via the python module **elasticsearch-dsl**.

I have a body that I am passing to the `update()` function in order to transfer some information to the index:

```
>>> hits = client.search(index='xyz', body=body_search)
>>> print hits['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['authors']
>>> [{u'id': u'None', u'name': u'Xyz'}, {u'id': u'None', u'name': u'Zyx'}, {u'id': None, u'name': u'Yzx'}]

>>> body_update = { "doc": { "authors": None } }
>>> body_update['doc']['authors'] = new_authors
>>> print body_update
>>> {'doc': {'authors': [{u'id': u'XYZ_0', u'name': u'Xyz'}, {u'id': u'ZYX_0', u'name': u'Zyx'}, {u'id': 'YZX_0', u'name': u'Yzx'}]}}

>>> client.update(index='xyz', doc_type='zyx', id=123, body=body_update)
>>> print client.search(index='xyz', body=body_search)['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['authors']
>>> [{u'id': u'XYZ_0', u'name': u'Xyz'}, {u'id': u'ZYX_0', u'name': u'Zyx'}, {u'id': None, u'name': u'Yzx'}]
```

The body contains the respective information, but not all of it is transfered. I checked that as expected, only one document is returned by the searches. No error messages. Same behavior on repetition (exact same authors).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just had to add `refresh=True` to the `update()` query.